# Norton 360: Clear "unrepairable virus detected" warning

Tags: norton-360

Norton made a misdiagnoses, as usual, when it found a "virus" on a CD. Of course, the CD is read-only so Norton couldn't destroy it, which made Norton sad. Problem is, I can't get rid of the stupid warning message. Anyone know how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open the suite from the icon in the tray. Click on Settings. Uncheck the Norton Tamper Protection to be able to delete the folder called "QBackup".

The common location is as follows (it's in a hidden folder, so it's hard to find; you'll have to enable the ability to view those):

On my Windows 7 system, it's under:

C:\ProgramData\Norton{0C55...6E7}\Norton\QBackup

It may be under:

C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Application data\Norton{..............}\Norton\QBackup

When done, recheck the Norton Tamper Protection from Settings.

Comment: Ended up uninstalling Norton because I hate it anyways, so I'll just assume this works. Thanks :) Hopefully someone else will find this useful.

Comment: I may be heading that way. Got it free via Comcast and I don't like it's heavy-handed interface. However, it is much leaner and faster than the state of Norton two years ago.